# Как заставить липкий блок липнуть?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Первый момент: здесь при просмотре, обратите пожалуйста внимание, почему-то блок №1 при прокрутке пропадает. Хотя, у меня он "скользит" без ошибок.

Второй момент: при прокрутке страницы вниз "липкий" блок сначала прилипает к верху, а в конце уже прокручивается. При прокрутке страницы вверх "липкий" блок прокручивается, а потом уже прилипает. Как его заставить при прокрутке страницы вниз вести себя также, как и при прокрутке страницы вверх? То есть, сначала блок прокручивается, после чего уже прилипает, но не наоборот.

И третий момент: в случае, если контента на странице совсем мало (имеется ввиду в блоке `.article`), то происходит "дерганье" липкого блока и страница не прокручивается вниз. Очень вам благодарен за помощь!

```js
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.stickyBox = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            notStickyBreakpoint: 100,
            spaceTop: 0,
            stoppper: true,
            stopperSpace: 0
        };
        var config = $.extend(defaults, options);
        if ($(window).innerWidth() <= config.notStickyBreakpoint) {
            return this;
        }
        var stopper;
        if (config.stopper !== false) {
            stopper = $(config.stopper).first();
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            var box = $(this);
            box.initialStyle = box.attr('style');
            box.parentElement = box.parent();
            box.alreadyStopped = false;
            setBoxProperties(box);
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                setBoxProperties(box);
                setBoxPosition(box);
            });
            setBoxPosition(box);
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                setBoxPosition(box);
            });
        });
        function setBoxProperties(box) {
            resetBox(box);
            var offsetTop = box.offset().top;
            var offsetLeft = box.offset().left;
            var boxSizing = box.css('box-sizing');
            var width;
            if (boxSizing == 'border-box') {
                width = box.outerWidth();
            } else {
                width = box.width();
            }
            box.intialOffsetTop = offsetTop;
            box.intialOffsetLeft = offsetLeft;
            box.initialWidth = width;
        }
        function setBoxPosition(box) {
            if (!box.alreadyStopped && (($(window).scrollTop() >= box.intialOffsetTop - config.spaceTop) || (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition))) {
                box.parentElement.css({
                    position: 'relative'
                });
                var position = 'fixed';
                var top = config.spaceTop;
                if (box.stopPosition !== undefined && $(window).scrollTop() >= box.stopPosition) {
                    position = 'absolute';
                    top = box.stopPosition + config.spaceTop - box.parentElement.offset().top;
                }
                box.css({
                    position: position,
                    top: top,
                    marginTop: 0,
                    width: box.initialWidth
                });
            } else {
                resetBox(box);
            }
        }
        function resetBox(box) {
            if (box.initialStyle !== undefined) {
                box.attr('style', box.initialStyle);
            } else {
                box.removeAttr('style');
            }

            if (config.stopper !== false && stopper.length > 0) {
                var stopperTop = stopper.offset().top;
                if (stopperTop > box.offset().top + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace) {
                    box.alreadyStopped = false;
                    box.stopPosition = stopperTop - (config.spaceTop + box.outerHeight() + config.stopperSpace);
                } else {
                    box.alreadyStopped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#sticky1').stickyBox({
  stopper: '.footer'
 });
 $('#sticky2').stickyBox({
  stopper: '.footer'
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {width:100%;height:100%;}
div {margin:0;padding:0;}
.container {
  display:block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
 min-width: 320px;
}
.wrapper {
  display:block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 100px;
}
.header {
  display:block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.article {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 100px;
}
.content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.aside {
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: -100px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar {
  display:block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100%;
 background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
.banner {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: chocolate;
  color: #fff;
}
.footer {
  display:block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="header">Лого</div>

<div class="article">
<div class="content">
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье 
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье 
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет, 
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет. 
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье<br>
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье<br>
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет,<br>
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет.<br>
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье<br>
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье<br>
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет,<br>
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет.<br>
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье<br>
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье<br>
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет,<br>
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет.<br>
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье<br>
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье<br>
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет,<br>
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет.<br>
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
<p>Когда б не смутное влеченье<br>
Чего-то жаждущей души,<br>
Я здесь остался б — наслажденье<br>
Вкушать в неведомой тиши:<br>
Забыл бы всех желаний трепет,<br>
Мечтою б целый мир назвал —<br>
И всё бы слушал этот лепет.<br>
Всё б эти ножки целовал…</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="aside"><div id="sticky1">
<h3>БЛОК №1</h3>
<p>Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный,<br>
К нему не зарастет народная тропа,<br>
Вознесся выше он главою непокорной<br>
Александрийского столпа.</p>
<p>Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный,<br>
К нему не зарастет народная тропа,<br>
Вознесся выше он главою непокорной<br>
Александрийского столпа.</p>
<p>Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный,<br>
К нему не зарастет народная тропа,<br>
Вознесся выше он главою непокорной<br>
Александрийского столпа.</p>
<p>Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный,<br>
К нему не зарастет народная тропа,<br>
Вознесся выше он главою непокорной<br>
Александрийского столпа.</p>
</div></div>

</div>

<div class="sidebar">
<p>Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный,<br>
К нему не зарастет народная тропа,<br>
Вознесся выше он главою непокорной<br>
Александрийского столпа.</p>
<div class="banner"><div id="sticky2">
<h3>БЛОК №2</h3>
</div></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="footer">Подвал</div>
```

Comment: вместо JS что у вас используется , можно две пары условий добавить, к каждому блоку по паре, на событити scroll, или здесь принципиально использовать jQuery.fn.stickyBox = function(op.....?? могу продемонстрировать, на вашем примере..

Comment: Я разрабатывал разные липкие элементы, и по сути там все намного проще, чем у Вас, ну если Вам надо только этот скрипт, то удачи в поиске решения!

Comment: Не хотите переписать все прилипающие блоки на `position: sticky`?